# How to use a main bib file with the Isabelle document preparation system?

Tags: git, symlink, isabelle

I have a main .bib file in a git repository and I would like to use it for all my Isabelle proof documents.

However, `isabelle build` refuses a .bib file that is outside the document root directory. I tried to use a symlink but that is not transferred through git -- I would use the same document on another machine.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You might also use a custom `build` script that copies the bib files to the output directly.

Comment: Indeed, that is a solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say anything about git and symlinks.

Concerning Isabelle document preparation, see [The Isabelle System Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf) about the `ROOT` file syntax, concerning `document_files` in particular.  The collective document files are copied into the document output directory, before invoking latex or bibtex jobs.  You can specify a *base directory* there to pick things from a different directory hierarchy.  E.g. like this:

```
document_files (in "/home/joe/some/where")
  "root.bib"
```